# Analysis of the Set x Set category.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

i want to analyze the product category of the Set category and itself.

The objects are (A,B) elements with A,B sets

Morphisms are (f,g):(A,B) -> (C,D) with f:A->C , G:B->D

Now, i want to see initial objects, terminal objects, product, coproduct and exponential in this category.

My idea is:

Initial object: product of empty sets ($\emptyset$, $\emptyset$) ,

Terminal objects: product of singleton sets ({x},{y})

Product: (X*Y, $\pi$X , $\pi$Y) is the product in a way that for an object (A,B) the morphism (f,g):A->X and (h,i):B->Y generates the unique morphism <(f,g),(h,i)> that commutes the diagram.

X*Y is the element (X,Y) with X and Y being each the product of two sets.

I'm having trouble finding the coproduct and exponential in this category. Can someone help me find them.

Coproduct in Set is the disjoint union, so it seems like here it would be the same
And the exponential in Set is the object B^A={f:A->B} so here it should be X^Y = {(f,g):X->Y} ?

Comment: Have you tried to check the universal properties?

Comment: Coproduct is componentwise disjoint union. The exponential $(B,B')^{(A,A')} = (B^A, {B'}^{A'})$. Now check the definitions.

Comment: Everything is pointwise - limits, colimits, exponentials, etc.